# Getting Gill Sans to display properly in IE

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm developing a website that uses the Gill Sans font. So far it displays properly on Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. Here's the css:

```
@font-face {font-family:"Gill Sans"; 
src:url(../../GillSansStd.otf);}
@font-face {font-family:"Gill Sans"; 
font-weight:bold; src:url(../../GillSansStd-Bold.otf);}
@font-face {font-family:"Gill Sans"; 
font-style:italic; src:url(../../GillSansStd-Italic.otf);}
```

I tried converting the .otf to .eot and adding a conditional statement for IE, but I couldn't get that to work either. I don't know much about fonts so please excuse me, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

When using FONT types that consist of two words, quotes must be placed on them so the browser does not read them as separate entries.

```
@font-face {font-family:""Gill Sans""; 
src:url(../../GillSansStd.otf);}
@font-face {font-family:""Gill Sans""; 
font-weight:bold; src:url(../../GillSansStd-Bold.otf);}
@font-face {font-family:""Gill Sans""; 
font-style:italic; src:url(../../GillSansStd-Italic.otf);}
```

More examples can be found here: [CSS Font Styles](http://www.htmlite.com/CSS004.php)

Answer (score 0):

See fonts.com [info](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype-imaging/gill-sans/roman/web-font) on using Gills Sans as web font.

Note that a normal license for the Gill Sans font does not allow use as web font, and some browsers may enforce this legal restriction as a technical limitation.